# Converting Json field & relational fields into multiple rows

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016

I am really new to Json & SQL Server. Since SQL Server 2016 can support Json values, i have a task in hand.

I have a SQL table with a CustomeID (int) Field & another field that holds a json array value which holds different elements that belongs to that unique customer.

Ex:

```
Customer ID | JsonCol 
55          | [{"Id":"12","Height":"150","Weight":"75","Colour":"White"}, 
              {"Id":"15","Height":"160","Weight":"85","Colour":"Brown"}]
65          | [{"Id":"16","Height":"155","Weight":"65","Colour":"Red"}, 
              {"Id":"20","Height":"167","Weight":"55","Colour":"Black"}]
```

I would like to do a query in SQL Server to get the following outcome, I dont know how to insert tables into this. But basically the output should repeat the Customer for every combination of data that the array has in the Json field

```
CustomerID   | ID | Height | Weight | Colour
55           | 12 | 150    | 75     | White
55           | 15 | 160    | 85     | Brown
65           | 16 | 155    | 65     | Red
65           | 20 | 167    | 55     | Black
```

Can someone so kindly give me an idea where to start. I have already tried all Microsoft articles around Json support.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`OPENJSON` with the default output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#option-1---openjson-with-the-default-output) to get the array elements and then [`OPENJSON` output with an explicit structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#option-2---openjson-output-with-an-explicit-structure) to get the elements. Put it together with `CROSS APPLY`s.

```
SELECT CustomerID,
       x.Id,
       x.Height,
       x.Weight,
       x.Colour
       FROM Customer C
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                           FROM OPENJSON(C.JsonCol)
                           CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(value)
                                 WITH (Id integer '$.Id',
                                       Height integer '$.Height',
                                       Weight integer '$.Weight',
                                       Colour nvarchar(8) '$.Colour')) x;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/80234/23)

Comment: Worked like a charm. The more i read it - the more i understood what it was doing. Thank you so much. Really appreciated!